# how to implement picture library look and feel in provider hosted App?

Tags: splist, design, provider-hosted-app, branding

How to implement the same view (design) of SharePoint list (picture or document library) in provider hosted App, for now I am using asp.net controls but the final view of app doesn't belong to SharePoint world anymore.

I have many problems in designing provider hosted App, so i need also real world advice.